# How to get a GluonObservableObject for removal an object with Gluon Connect?

Tags: gluon-mobile

I want to remove an object from the DB on the server. I'm using

```
RestClient del = RestClient.create().method("DELETE")
                                    .host("http://localhost:8080/host")
                                    .path("path");

DataProvider.removeObject(???, 
    del.createObjectDataRemover(MyClass.class)
```

I need to get a `GluonObservableObject<MyClass>` somehow but I don't see how as it doesn't have a constructor I can use. I also don't understand why I need to pass a `GluonObservableObject` instead of the object itself like with `storeObject`. I have an object I want to store/remove - i pass it.

I also tried retrieving objects from `GluonObservableList` but these are also just objects and not observables.

How do I remove an object?

Comment: `DataProvider.removeObject` is intended for removing an object from a data source, not from the database. Did you check the [cloudlink-rest-connector](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/cloudlink-rest-connector) sample? There is a `NoteService::remove` method to remove the item from the database, which is called by `ListHandler::removeItem`. You could implement those methods in your server, and then you'll just need a GET/POST RestClient with the path `"/remove/{id}"`.

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks. Shouldn't I use DELETE to request removal and not GET/POST?

Comment: Well, probably you could define the REST endpoint with `@DELETE` as well.